# django-filters form not showing(only the submit button does)

Tags: html, django, forms, django-forms, django-filter

template

```
<form method="get">
    {{ filter.form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Press" />
</form>
{% for obj in filter.qs %}
    {{ obj.WorkType }} - ${{ obj.desired_wage }}<br />
{% endfor %}
```

views

```
@login_required(login_url='login')
def ListingsPage(request):
review = Review.objects.all()

    filter = Profilefilter(request.GET, queryset=Profile.objects.all())
    
    context = {"profile":profile,"review":review,"filter":filter}
    
    return render(request,"base/Listings.html",context)
```

filters.py

```
import django_filters
from .models import Profile

class Profilefilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
name = django_filters.CharFilter(lookup_expr='iexact')

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ['WorkType', 'gender']
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('Listings/', views.ProfileSearch, name='profile_search_bar'),
    path('',views.hello,name="home"),
    path('Listings/', views.ListingsPage,name="listings"),
```

It is supposed to be showing the filters but doesn't render anything, only the submit button shows up. I think it is something to do with passing the context, not sure tho

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `qs` for query filter

```py
  def ListingsPage(request):
      review = Review.objects.all()
  
      filter = Profilefilter(request.GET, queryset=Profile.objects.all())
      review = filter.qs
      
      context = {"profile":profile,"review":review,"filter":filter}
      
      return render(request,"base/Listings.html",context)
```